# Creating a Sliding Menu with Overlaying Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, slidingdrawer

I'm trying to create an activity that has a `sliding drawer` at the bottom and allows the user to slide up and reveal a menu (shown as the grey area in my pictures). I'm currently having two issues:

1. **Sliding Animation:** When the user begins to drag, I want the Text and image to dynamically re-size and move as the drawer is dragged up *(see pictures below)*. I have a working sliding drawer, but no animations.
2. **Round Image:** I want the round image *(seen in the pictures below)* to sit halfway on the sliding layout, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Here are the pictures showing what I'm trying to achieve:

Sliding drawer fully closed: [link](http://s17.postimg.org/5o4zyjrj3/stage0.png)

Sliding drawer open a litte: [link](http://s21.postimg.org/rge9m9pxz/stage1.png)

Sliding drawer open more: [link](http://s21.postimg.org/mo4gatv9z/stage2.png)

Sliding drawer open all the way: [link](http://s3.postimg.org/oiwusbj6r/stage3.png)

*(sorry, I don't have the rep to directly post the images)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Design Library's [Collapsing Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) class which you should check instead of reinventing the wheel. There's open source sample app you may want to check:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: thanks! This is awesome. I'm still a little stuck on one thing: In the sample app you linked, they use a `FloatingActionButton` which has a cool _zoom out_ animation as you scroll up. I'd like to implement something similar, but on an image view (since I don't want a `FloatingActionButton`) however I can't seem to find out where this animation is being set. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to get familiar with [Coordinator Layout's Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.Behavior.html) and have this implemented